# how to track googleplusone button clicks?

Tags: asp.net, google-plus-one

I would like to track googleplusone clicks without using google analytics. Is there any functionality available for this? I tried to google it but to no avail.

UPDATE: I tried this but the callback is not fired?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">    </script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
          function helloWorld(plusone) { alert('+1 Triggered, State=' + plusone.state);  } 
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <g:plusone  callback="helloWorld"></g:plusone>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the callback attribute on the +1 tag to a javascript function.

This function is called after the user clicks the +1 button. The callback function must be in the global namespace and may accept a single parameter, which will be a JSON object with the following structure:

```
{
  "href": target URL,
  "state": "on"|"off"
}
```

The state property is set to "on" for a +1, and "off" for the removal of a +1.

Comment: i tried this but the callback does not function? see update above